# Generate additional custom method with jaxb-xjc

Tags: java, methods, xsd, jaxb, xjc

There's some way to generate a custom method within an class generated with JAXB.

I search around tutorials, including oracle's tutorial, but I didn't find clear instructions how can I custom methods to a generated class described on XML Schema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write an XJC plugin:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html

Comment: Excellent! I think that it's exactly what I am looking for ...  I'll try it and comment here about results! Thanks!

Comment: I used an existent implementation of Code Injection, exactly the same described on article. It worked as I expected. Thanks!

Comment: the article seems to be old. Is there any new advanced ways to do the same ?

Answer (score 7):

I have found the following to be the best way to add custom behavior:

https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-adding-behaviors

You can implement the custom behavior for a JAXB generated class BaseType in a custom class BaseTypeExt that extends the JAXB generated class BaseType.

You also tell JAXB to use your extended class BaseTypeExt (instead of the BaseType class it extends) as the base class for all classes that normally would have extended the BaseType class.

I used this successfully to override the toString() method in my generated class BaseType.

This seems simpler than writing an XJC plugin.