# How to add extra methods in generated classes using jaxb-xjc schema

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Is there's a way to have extra methods in an class generated with JAXB ... To be more specific I would like make changes in my .xsd files and not code some methods in a "first.java" class and then make my .xsd generated classes inherit from "first.java" .. My goal is to modify only my .jaxb file .. so can we create methods with .xsd ?

I have an ".xsd" file that generates a class. And I want to know if it's possible to add to this generated class some other methods besides the getters and setters.
I search around tutorials and some StackOverflow topics but I didn't find  instructions on how can I add custom methods to a generated class described on XML Schema.

Here's my .xsd file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.1">
    <xs:element name="Myclass" />
    <xs:complexType name="Myclass">
        <xs:complexContent>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And here's the class generated with this .xsd file :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Myclass")
public class Myclass
{

}
```

Here's an example of a class that I want to generate with

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Myclass")
public class Myclass
{
     public String method(){
                return "Hello";
       }
}
```

Thank's in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate additional custom method with jaxb-xjc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875469/generate-additional-custom-method-with-jaxb-xjc)

Comment: Thank's for your reply, but I want to modify only my .xsd file and the solutions proposed in this article require creating manually some .java files ..

Answer (score 1):

If you receive the XSDs from a client and they can change often, I would recommend not making changes to the XSDs as a design decision. I would recommend the java route as mentioned on the JAXB documentation:
https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-adding-behaviors